How to reconstruct the vol surface given Level, Slope and Curvature
Assuming I have a prediction of Realized Vol, Skewness (Slope) and Kurtosis (Curvature) of the underlying of an Equity European option.
How to get IV(log(S/K)) at any point on the curve as a function of Log-Moneyness using the above 3 values. Obviously for S = K, the value will be my estimate of Realized Vol.

There are several ways to do this. The most straightforward is probably using the Gram-Charlier expansion of the density. As discussed in this thread and references therein, the IV can then be expressed as
$$
IV(K) \approx \sigma \left( 1 - \frac{\kappa_3}{3!} d_1 + \frac{ \kappa_4}{4!} (d_1^2 - 1) \right)
$$
with
$$
d_1 = \frac{\log S_0/K + \frac12 \sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
$$
and $\kappa_3, \kappa_4$ are the third and fourth cumulants respectively. The $\sigma$ above is actually a rather arbitrary constant, but usually taken as ATM IV. However you can use (your forecast of) the instantaneous spot vol or realized vol as well if you want.
So if you have a forecast/view on the realized vol and cumulants you can use the above approximation to find $IV(K)$.
Personally I'd only use the approximation up to say delta 25 and extrapolate using other methods, eg SVI.
